# Investigating long TypeScript compile times

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm investigating why the compilation time for my Angular 2.0 TypeScript project went from around 4 seconds to around 15 seconds in a relatively short time.

I came across the very useful, but seemingly undocumented `--diagnostics` switch.

For example, here's what I get when running `tsc --noEmit --diagnostics` on my project now:

```
Files:             231
Lines:           50872
Nodes:          170067
Identifiers:     65994
Symbols:       7712123
Types:          407677
Memory used:   600554K
I/O read:        0.43s
I/O write:       0.00s
Parse time:      1.13s
Bind time:       0.34s
Check time:     10.17s
Emit time:       0.00s
Total time:     11.64s
```

Here's what I get when I run the same command on an earlier version of the project.

```
Files:             197
Lines:           30882
Nodes:          124208
Identifiers:     46201
Symbols:       5856945
Types:           10989
Memory used:    80412K
I/O read:        0.03s
I/O write:       0.00s
Parse time:      0.60s
Bind time:       0.27s
Check time:      0.93s
Emit time:       0.00s
Total time:      1.79s
```

The number of `Types` has gone way up, and so has the `Check time`.

Is it possible to get more detailed/verbose output from `--diagnostics`?

NodeJS v4.4.3, TypeScript v1.8.10. This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",

    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false,

    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "removeComments": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Seems I have found the culprit in my case. I did it the hard way; my process:

1. Find the commit that made the compilation slow. Go through the history commit-by-commit and check the compile times.
2. Comment out the changed code until the offending lines are found.

Before the offending commit, I consistently got compile times of around 2-4 seconds, after the commit - 13-17 seconds.

In my case, I have a class, with a `accessTokenGetter` field, which was initialized in the constructor:

```
export class JwtConfig {
    //...
    accessTokenGetter: () => Observable<string>;
    //...
      constructor(private config?: IJwtConfig) {
          // ...
          this.accessTokenGetter = this.config.accessTokenGetter || (() => Observable.of(null));
      }
}
```

The second part of the initialization `|| (() => Observable.of(null));` was causing the slowness. Commenting it out or adding a type annotation got the compile time back down. Since Observable is generic, it seems like the TypeScript compiler needs a hint to narrow down some type checks it needs to do. My initialization now reads as:

```
//...
this.accessTokenGetter = this.config.accessTokenGetter || (() => Observable.of(<string>null));
//...
```

`Observable.of(null as string))` also seems to do the job. There were a couple of other places where adding a type annotation sped compilation up.

Hope this helps someone.

Still, if there's a facility in the compiler to the answer faster - I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: Thanks, I encountered the same problem. Learned rule to avoid it: add type annotation whenever possible

Comment: Wow, this is crazy. It would be great if there was an automated way to track down slow inferences like these.

Comment: You could benefit from `git bisect` with the compilation time as pivot/condition. That would've taken just few minutes to bisect 1000s commits. Setup is probably less than an hour, and you could re-use it for future investigations

Comment: Running `tsc --noEmit --diagnostics` resulted in check time of 0.00s. I figured it was because the result was cached in `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo`, so be sure to delete this file before running diagnostics.

Answer (score 6):

I could speed up the compile process from 15 sec. to 6-7 sec. by changing this single line of code:

```
// slow:
// ...
.flatMap((receivedObj: MyType) => {
    let nextObservable: Observable<MySecondType> = this.dependingPut(receivedObj);
    return nextObservable || new Observable((observer) => {
            observer.next(undefined);
        });
});


// fast:
.flatMap((receivedObj: MyType) => {
    let nextObservable: Observable<MySecondType> = this.dependingPut(receivedObj);  
    return nextObservable || new Observable<MySecondType>((observer) => { // <--- use the generics!
            observer.next(undefined);
        });
});
```

From the Typescript handbook (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}

// ...

let output = identity("myString");  // type of output will be 'string'
```

> "Notice that we didn’t have to explicitly pass the type in the angle
>   brackets (<>), the compiler just looked at the value "myString", and
>   set T to its type. While type argument inference can be a helpful tool
>   to keep code shorter and more readable, you may need to explicitly
>   pass in the type arguments as we did in the previous example when the
>   compiler fails to infer the type, as may happen in more complex
>   examples."

In my case it didn't fail; the type inference just took a very long time (by the way, it consumed plenty of memory as well).
Before you start to build workarounds, go back in your revision history and try to identify the bad revision. To be sure that the compiler is the culprit, use the [--diagnostics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) option. If the returned statistics returns a high "Check time" value, then inspect your code for missing types.

Answer (score 1):

For me, slowdowns were due to imports like `import "./file.ts";`. Removing the `.ts` extension makes things 90% faster: `import "./file";`

Answer (score 0):

Compiler is known to be slow, you can use compiler in watch mode `tsc -w` or switch to `webpack` and `ts-loader` which expose `transpileOnly` option (no time consuming checks).

Comment: Thanks. We use `gulp-typescript` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) for watching for changes. It supports incremental compilation. Even with watching, I consistently get 12 to 18 second builds. But the builds used to be faster and not that much code was added and we're just getting started. Something change must have caused the issue, but it'd be very time consuming to search commit-by-commit.

Comment: i tried gulp-typescript and built-in Intellij Idea compiler, but it was too slow, about 8 seconds after each change, unacceptable. Now i'm using webpack and ts-loader with transpileonly option, recompile time is about 0.5s.

Answer (score 0):

In my case compile time was around 15-30 seconds. After `tsc --noEmit --diagnostics` command I've noticed that I'm building 2k files. Solution was to exclude all files from `node_modules` folder:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {...},
   "exclude": [
     "node_modules"
   ]
}
```

It is a good idea to exclude `typings` folder too.

Comment: Yes, agreed. But I had already excluded both when I started having my problem. Regarding typings I'm not so sure - depending on how you have your project set up, i.e. if you don't use triple-slash references (`/// <reference ..`), you might need to leave a part of typings subtree in - as I've done in my case - I only exclude typings for node (`typings/main`).